# Routing subnets per interface on a dual nic windows server

Tags: routing, windows-server-2012, ipv4

The server I'm working on has 2 NICs.

```
C:\Windows\system32>route print
===========================================================================
Interface List
20...00 50 56 ad 02 3b ......Intel(R) 82574L Gigabit Network Connection #2
12...00 50 56 ad 2f 8a ......Intel(R) 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
13...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
===========================================================================
```

The IPv4 addresses are:

```
C:\Windows\system32>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration
Ethernet adapter Ethernet1:
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.112
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.2

Ethernet adapter Ethernet0:
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::4af:f246:6f29:8145%12
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.20
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.2
```

My goal is to route traffic out the 192.168.1.20 adapter by default but also to route a specific set of subnets out via the 192.168.1.112 adapter. The route command I'm issuing is

```
route -p add 207.211.31.1 mask 255.255.255.128 192.168.1.2 METRIC 10 IF 20
OK!
```

But the end result doesn't look to me as if I'm accomplishing my goal.

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.2     192.168.1.20     20
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.2    192.168.1.112     40
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.1.20    266
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.1.112    266
     192.168.1.20  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.20    266
    192.168.1.112  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.112    266
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.20    266
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.112    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.1.20    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.1.112    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.20    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.112    266
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.2      10
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.2      30
     207.211.31.1  255.255.255.128      192.168.1.2      10
===========================================================================
```

Am I going about this in an incorrect way? Is this correct and I'm not reading the output right?

D

Comment: Just curious, why do you have two NICs on the same VLAN (192.168.1.0/24)? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The server will run an Exchange Hub Transport roll that needs 2 instances of an SMTP server running on 25. Each will have its own authentication types and allowed subnets defined. One for internal routing between servers and one for external mail delivery and receipt. The gateway firewall is setup to only allow in/out from the ip that is used for in/out mail.

Comment: Remove the default gateway on the internal routing and route between any internal subnets using static routes